# Why is nvidia-smi not working on deep learning ami + aws g5.xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, gpu

I want to use tensorflow on aws g5.xlarge. For AMI, I used AWS Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 18.04) ver 50.0. But when I start the instance and try nvidia-smi, the following error exists. Why am I getting the following error even though I used deep learning ami?

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://repost.aws/questions/QUNR0L1sSIRd-e1zeRIoEc1Q/gpu-fails-to-intialize-on-g-5-xlarge-instance? Someone asked the same question on AWS questions.